# How does python evaluate A<X<B

Tags: python

There is the code that I saw was this.

`def min(x,y,z):
   if z<=x<=y:
      return z
   elif x<=y and x<z:
      return x
   elif y<=z and y<=x:
      return y`

They ask the following if `z<=x<=y` is changed to the following `(z<=x)<=y` or `z<=x and x<=y` does it make a difference?

Since I know that python always evaluate left to right base on order precedence, I would like to know if `(z<=x)<=y` is correct or not.

I would like to also know about what happens if there is multiple and/or in a conditions such as:

if `A and B or C` vs `A or B and C` vs `A and B or C and D`.

Is it computed as `(A and B) or C` or `A and (B or C)`?

Comment: You say that some unspecified "they" did "the following modification". What modification did "they" do, specifically? Did whoever you're talking about literally write `(A < X) < B / A < X and X < B`, with two occurrences of each variable and a division? Or did they replace `A < X < B` with one of `(A < X) < B` or `A < X and X < B`? If so, which one?

Comment: P.S. I have edited to make more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [**source**](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/precedence-associativity):

> Some operators like assignment operators and comparison operators do not have associativity in Python. There are separate rules for sequences of this kind of operator and cannot be expressed as associativity.
>
> For example, x < y < z neither means (x < y) < z nor x < (y < z). x < y < z is equivalent to x < y and y < z, and is evaluates from left-to-right.

Is it computed as (A and B) or C or A and (B or C)? It should be (A and B) or C since Logical AND has higher precedence than Logical OR.